# javascript save binary data to jpeg file

Tags: javascript, binary-data

I am building an app that talks to a camera that implements the [OSC standard from Google](https://developers.google.com/streetview/open-spherical-camera/)
The api call that i have a pb with is the one that returns the binary data: [camera.getImage](https://developers.google.com/streetview/open-spherical-camera/reference/camera/getimage)

I am trying for a day now to display or save this data as a jpeg file ... i tried many possible combinations but nothing

So can anyone help me either display or save this binary data to a file?

thanks,
Rares

Answer (score 0):

You could use a modified version of the snippet below to convert the binary output in `camera.getImage` to a `jpg` file.

```
def getImage(fileUri):
    url = request("commands/execute")
    body = json.dumps({"name": "camera.getImage",
         "parameters": {
            "fileUri": fileUri,
            "_type": "image"
         }
         })
    with open('output.jpg', 'wb') as handle:
        response = requests.post(url, data=body, stream=True)
        for block in response.iter_content(1024):
            handle.write(block)
```

Comment: i would do that but from what i see the part that handles the binary data is the one after with ... and it is a normal file write except the stream property which i do not think has an equivalent in javscript

Comment: what i read so far si that one of the functions one should use is btoa but if i try that on my binary code i get an error telling me that it contains characters outside of Latin1 ... that means the output is a an unicode string ...i really do not know how to write that to a file ... i am doing this app in phonegap btw